# URL-Manipulation with javascript

Tags: javascript, url

I am new to javascript and kinda noobish... my first code will be an url-manipulator...

I want to do the following: I want a url like

```
http://www.example.com/index.php?show=vods&play=1234
```

to be manipulated so a `"&res=480p"` will be added everytime I browse a site with `"?show=vods&play=XXXX"`  where X is between 0 and 9 ...

```
Example: 
http://www.example.com/index.php?show=vods&play=1234 [original url]
-->
http://www.example.com/index.php?show=vods&play=1234&res=480p [manipulated url]
```

I know, I am at beginner-level, so please can someone gimme a hint, solve my problem or can give me something to read so I can solve it on my own?

Comment: Have you tried googling up, doing some research ?

Comment: i am new to js and tried google with "javascript url manipulation" "javascript change url" ans stuff like that... but i don't know exactly where to start... sry :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change url in javascript using window.location.href

something like this:
window.location.href = window.location.href + '&res=480p'

Comment: yeah, it works... but it keeps adding &res=480p every 2 seconds.. o.O

Comment: well you have to check if the url already has res=480p

if ( window.location.href.indexOf('res=480p') == -1 )
  window.location.href = window.location.href + '&res=480p'

Comment: yeah... obvious... no i know how to add something to an url and how to check first, if my change is still there...

now it works like a charm... thank you very much for your help :)

Comment: You can change the URL of the current page using `window.location`. That's not the same as manipulating generic URLs.